# Managing iPod playlists?

Tags: 12.04, music, rhythmbox, ipod

OK, I know very similar questions have been asked before.  But I have searched for the last week, and cannot figure out how to manage iPod playlists on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

All the "usual suspects" (Rhythmbox, Banshee, Amarok, etc.) are completely unable to edit/create/delete iPod playlists correctly.  The only program I've ever had any success with was gtkpod, which is unusable on 12.04 64-bit.

So what options do I have? I have a 4th generation video iPod (sort of old).  The default music player, Rhythmbox, *seems* to put playlists on the iPod, but all it does is *append*.  So adding one file to a playlist causes Rhythmbox to double every other file in the playlist!

Is it truly impossible to use both Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit and have a manageable iPod?

Thanks!

Comment: try this- http://www.libimobiledevice.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While finding how to use iPhone 3G as a Wi-Fi source under 12.04 64-bit, I found that the latest version of `libimobiledevice` gives support for several of Apple devices.

Now I can edit my songs for my iPod, shuffle 4G via Rhythmbox, and also I can tether Wi-Fi via my iPhone 3GS 32GB under iOS 5.1.1.

As an advice, visit the project [website](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) and read some documentation and give it a try.

I warn you, this is not the same as iTunes, remember this is open source and one of the main aims of Apple it's totally the opposite. You are going to be able to manage your music, podcasts, videos, etc. but advance settings like playlist editing, advance sync and settings maybe will be unavailable for now.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Even I was facing the same problem Rhythmbox, but i tried and saw that gtkpod version 2.1.1 is working perfectly fine for my playlists on Ubuntu 12.04 Precise 64-bit. I have a 5th Generation iPod Nano with Camera.

Install gtkpod from the Software Centre: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gtkpod/